# Is application data preserved across application updates?

Tags: iphone

I'm writing an iPhone/iPad app, and I'm wondering if future updates will wipe the application's sandbox data (this is of vital importance for me since my app will use in app purchase). I've already googled around but couldn't find any definite answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application data stored in sandbox folders is preserved during updates. Normally updates just replace application bundle leaving other folders untouched.